# Looking for a word for an "outhouse" inside the house

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, slang

I need a word for a restroom that does not have running water - where there is a pit toilet or a composting toilet instead of a flush toilet.  If it were detached from a house, I am sure it would be called an outhouse.   What is it called when it is in the house?

So the function of the room is the same as a restroom, it is the room where you would go to relieve oneself, but the facilities in the room are incongruous with the present definition of a restroom.

I am sure that people had such room prior to the invention of plumbing, but I cannot find any mention of it.

We have created such a room in our house for when the electric is out - which means we do not have water as we are on an electric well.   But we are at a loss as to what to call it because it is definitely not a restroom.

Comment: I think that before the invention of plumbing, pit toilets were carefully build outside. They used chamber pots inside.

Comment: I suggest [**garderobe**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/garderobe). The medieval toilet was an indoor room, without modern facilities. Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garderobe).

Comment: @WeatherVane - you certainly need a castle to have a garderobe.

Comment: @user067531 everyone's home is their castle.

Comment: @WeatherVane - yes, medieval times, though, are a bit far back.

Comment: What's wrong with restroom? It doesn't necessarily imply running water.

Comment: @user067531 it is true, even today. Please see [this](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/an-englishmans-home-is-his-castle).

Comment: @nollidge the house *already has* a restroom.

Comment: @WeatherVane That still doesn't make it *not* a restroom, buildings can have multiple restrooms.

Answer (score 4):

*Latrine* can be used to describe such a room. By itself, *latrine* can refer to something either indoors or outdoors (e.g. [Mediterranean, Malta or undulant fever](https://archive.org/details/b21364539/page/180), 1897 uses it to mean either, mostly hand-flushed), with outdoors being more likely for obvious reasons.

A bit more unambiguous is *indoor latrine*:

> If you had to go to the bathroom, there was an indoor latrine, half a flight down. You would go in, take the wooden cover off a hole and sit on it. —[Intrigue, Capitalism, Love: My True Story](https://books.google.com/books?id=B2Yr3_ELSb8C&pg=PA33&dq=%22indoor+latrine%22)

Answer (score 3):

[**Privy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/privy) gives the sense of having a room with a non-mechanical toilet.  While this is often a synonym for outhouse, the description doesn't contain the notion of being outside, so it retains its validity for an indoor model.

The usage derives from its being a place of privacy to do one's business.

[**Toilet**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toilet) also has validity here. The room can be named for the appliance whether it's a flush toilet or not.  Interestingly the word derives from:

> French toilette cloth on which items used for grooming are placed, from Middle French, piece of batiste, from diminutive of toile cloth.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/privy) gives: A toilet located in a small shed **outside** a house or other building.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure. Because that's where most are located. As I said, *usually* a synonym for outhouse. But it's original sense derives from being a place of privacy.

Comment: Yes, _privy_ is appropriate for the time before flush toilets became the norm. Incidentally, in British English the primary meaning of _outhouse_ is just a shed; we would say _outside lavatory/toilet/loo_.